# How to install Python2.7 on Cygwin?

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu, unix, installation, cygwin

4 years ago, I using `apt-cyg` can install Python2.7.x directly, successfully, without any error

But now, I can't find Python2 in cygwin list

so I try to through complipe source on cygwin, and get failed

I also try to through complipe source on WSL2, then copy some dir to cygwin, and try to `make install` in the copyed dir, and get failed again

... why ... Is it because some key packages are missing? (I install gcc, make, cmake, wget, ...)

What is the correct way to install it??

Comment: You can try to download from https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7/ and build it.

Comment: @Philippe bro ... , I know, in my description, i do three attempt: (1) `apt-cyg` (2) build source on cygwin (3) build scorce on WSL2 and copy and make install on cygwin. All failed

Comment: If you have done `(2) build source on cygwin`, maybe ask another question about the errors you got.

Comment: @Philippe ok...  the error message too long to ... you know, I can't locate problem. fotunately, I maybe solve it, It's ... oh crazy

Answer (score 1):

I solve it by myself

method as follow

when you run

- `tar -zxvf Python-2.7.x...`
- `./configure --prefix=...`
- `make`

STOP HERE, and find the file `fficonfig.py`,
change some texts as follow:

```
ffi_platforms['X86_WIN64'] ---> ffi_platforms['X86_64-unknown-cygwin']
```

and

```
'X86_64': ['src/x86/ffi64.c', 'src/x86/unix64.S', 'src/x86/ffi.c', 'src/x86/sysv.S'],
(add this line) 'X86_64-unknown-cygwin': ['src/x86/ffi64.c', 'src/x86/unix64.S', 'src/x86/ffi.c', 'src/x86/sysv.S'],
```

save it, THEN `make insatall`

will get success already, maybe there are some small errors, but you can run most file you need to run ...

Answer (score 1):

Python 2.7 was removed from Cygwin on Last July
https://cygwin.com/pipermail/cygwin-announce/2023-July/011186.html

If you really want you can install it using the Cygwin Time Machine
http://www.crouchingtigerhiddenfruitbat.org/Cygwin/timemachine.html

Considering that python 2.7 is ancient  and discontinued upstream, you should move to a less obsolete version